# Split document and save each part as a file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word file that contains multiple people and their details.

I need to split this file into single files for each person.

This is the code, most of it is from examples I found.

I need to split the file by the delimiter (Personal).
Each file needs to be named by their ID number situated just below the delimiter.

```
Sub SplitNotes (delim As String)

    Dim sText As String
    Dim sValues(10) As String
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim arrNotes
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim Test As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Response As Integer

    arrNotes = Split(ActiveDocument.Range, delim)
    Response = MsgBox("This will split the document into " & UBound(arrNotes) + 1 & " sections.Do you wish to proceed?", 4)
    If Response = 7 Then Exit Sub
    For I = LBound(arrNotes) To UBound(arrNotes)
        If Trim(arrNotes(I)) <> "" Then
            X = X + 1
            Set doc = Documents.Add
            doc.Range = arrNotes(I)
             'Find "EID: "
             doc.Range.Find.Text = "EID: "
             'Select whole line
             Selection.Expand wdLine
             'Assign text to variable
             sText = Selection.Text
             'Remove spaces
             sText = Replace(sText, " ", "")
             'Split string into values
             sValues = Split(sText, ":")

            strFilename = "Testing"
            doc.SaveAs ThisDocument.Path & "\" & strFilename & Format(X, "Agent")
            doc.Close True
        End If
    Next I
End Sub

Sub Test()
    'delimiter
    SplitNotes "Name:"
End Sub
```

The Word document is set out as follows:

```
    Personal 
    Name: John Smith 
    EID: Alph4num3r1c (Not a set length as i know of) 
    Details follow on from here
```

My problem is getting the ID number and using it in the save as function.
I don't have a complete understanding of how the split function works.

Comment: first- what and where is your problem? second- to help you precisely I'd like to see sample of your document, please add a text structure here or upload anywhere in Internet.

Comment: So their ID is the first bit of text after the split? Is it a defined length? Is it always followed by a space?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys.
The Word document is set out as follows

Comment: The Word document is set out as follows:


                       Personal
Name: John Smith
ID: Alph4num3r1c (Not a set length as i know of)
Details follow on from here


Thinking about this I should probably split the document on "Personal"

My problem exactly is getting the ID number and using it in the save as function.
Also I don't have a complete understanding of how the split function works.

Comment: Please update your question with the document description in your comment, it is very hard to read and understand in the comment format.

Comment: Also, if you know the exact position of the ID I think it will be easier to find it using string handling functions (`Left()`, `Right()`, `Mid()` etc) instead of Find.

Comment: @OlleSjögren I do know its location, but how do I reach it without using Find?

Comment: @Skitlz For instance, `Mid("EID: Alph4num3r1c", Len("EID: Alph4num3r1c") - InStr("EID: Alph4num3r1c", ":"))` would give you `Alph4num3r1c`.

Comment: A bit hard to read, I guess... maybe `Split` is a better option.

Comment: @OlleSjögren Oh ok so you mean like this?
`sValues = Mid(sText,4,len(sText)-4)`

Comment: I guess `sValues = Mid(sText, 4)` would do it? That way you remove `"EID: "` from the beginning of the string (including the space). No need to pass the length of the string to return if you want everything to the right of `": "`.

Answer (score 0):

Split function splits a string into array of strings based on a delimeter. 
For eg:

```
Dim csvNames, arrNames
csvNames = "Tom,Dick,Harry"
arrNames = split(csvNames,",")
```

Now arrNames is an array containing 3 elements. You can loop through the elements like this:

```
Dim i
For i = 0 to UBound(arrNames)
    response.write arrNames(i) & "<br />"
Next
```

Now applying split function to solve your problem.
Read the line you are interested in into a variable. Lets say we have,

```
Dim lineWithID, arrKeyValuePair
lineWithID = "EID: Alph4num3r1c"
```

Split it into an array using colon

```
arrKeyValuePair = Split(lineWithID,":")
```

Now, arrKeyValuePair(1) will contain your EID

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still valid I have some solution regarding file name you search.
I didn't check all part of your code (so I did but I don't have your original document to make full analysis). Back to file name- you could use below simple logic to extract name from newly created doc:

```
'...beginning of your code here
'next part unchanged >>
For I = LBound(arrNotes) To UBound(arrNotes)
        If Trim(arrNotes(I)) <> "" Then
            X = X + 1
            Set doc = Documents.Add
            doc.Range = arrNotes(I)
'<<until this moment

'remove or comment your code here!!

'and add new part of the code to search for the name
    Selection.Find.Execute "EID:"
    Selection.MoveRight wdWord, 1
    Selection.Expand wdWord
    strFilename = Trim(Selection.Text)

'and back to your code- unchanged
            doc.SaveAs ThisDocument.Path & "\" & strFilename & Format(X, "Agent")
            doc.Close True
        End If
Next I
'...end of sub and other ending stuff
```

I check it and works quite ok for me.